Next14 Image tag with 500 error in EC2 deploy
I'm using Next14 app router and deploying with EC2.
Some Images break with 500 status error. NOT ALL BUT SOME,,
I got all proper set in next.config.js remotePatterns, so this is not the problem.
I tried to deploy on Vercel, and in this case images were just fine with 200 status code.
I don't know why only in EC2 environment and only some of the images are broke.
If someone getting the same problem please help.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/WixyGBmw.png)

next.config.js remotePatterns

 remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "**",
        port: "",
        pathname: "**",
      },

seems to work at first time but actually it didn't

referrer policy
set the referrer policy to 'no-referrer'
seems to work at first time but actually it didn't

